How to icrease button font icon keeping button size in JavaFX?
I have two buttons in the toolbar. One button has only text, while the other has a font icon and text. Both the text size and icon size are set in ems (no px!). I want to increase the size of the icon, but I need both buttons to have the same height
This is my code:
public class NewMain extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var textButton = new Button("SomeText");

        var fontIcon = new Label("A");
        fontIcon.getStyleClass().add("my-icon");
        var textAndIconButton = new Button("SomeText", fontIcon);
        textAndIconButton.getStyleClass().add("icon-button");

        var toolBar = new ToolBar(textButton, textAndIconButton);
        toolBar.setMinHeight(40);
        var root = new VBox(toolBar);
        var scene = new Scene(root, 400, 200);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(NewMain.class.getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

CSS:
.root {
    -fx-font-size:16px;
}

.button {
    -fx-padding: 0.4em;
    -fx-font-size: 1em;
}

.my-icon {
    -fx-font-size: 1.4em;
}
.icon-button {
    -fx-padding: 0.2em 0.4em 0.2em 0.4em;
}

And this is the result:

As you see the their heights are not equal. Could anyone say how to do it using CSS?

Maybe increase the font in one of them and set a preferred height value for both of them?

Do you need the Buttons to be direct children of the Toolbar?  I imagine you could set each Button's maxHeight to Double.MAX_VALUE and place the two of them in a single HBox.
